# Help with this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> Today I have to attend a meeting with DGM sales at 12:30 PM, so I will move from office at 10:30 AM.

Comment: Because ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎unicorns.

Answer (score 2):

The proper form of your sentence would be:

> Today I have to attend a meeting with DGM sales at 12:30 PM, so I [have to / will / need to] leave [my / the] office at 10:30 AM.

However, in future, please consider asking such questions at the [English Language Learners' StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), as they are more suited there. Thank you! :)